Crash in static i386 Linux exe
This simple testcase:
#include <unistd.h>

void _start(void) {
        _exit(0);
}

crashes when run on Debian 12.6 i386.
Compiled with gcc -lc -nostdlib -static -Os. Note that this is on an i386 version of Debian.
In gdb:
 0x804905b <_exit+59>                    call   *%gs:0x10  

$gs is 0.
It still crashes if I remove the call to _exit.
Is Debian i386 borked when it comes to running static exes without main? I have no problem on amd64 systems (FreeBSD 14.0 with clang and Fedora 39). Also no problem on FreeBSD when compiling for i386.
UPDATE:
On Fedora 39 amd64 glibc 2.39 GCC 14.2.1, same problem.

Note: Debian is less relevant (but it help): you should write the compiler version, and kernel version, and the library version you link. -- Maybe googling you may get discussion on the porter and get some hints, else it may be a very niche problem. Or ask on a Debian mailing list where people doing architecture port may spot quickly the problem. -- And remove _exit(0) if it makes no difference. To me it seems a incompatibility libc and kernel

This is on a fresh install this morning, everything installed with apt. Are you saying that apt installs default packages (in this case, glibc-static) that are incompatible with the kernel?

Maybe. i386 is obsolete, so I'm not surprised that some change where not seen. In any case: please provide version numbers (also for the other cases (distribution) you tested.

In the manual page of exit according to the following:

Up to glibc 2.3, the _exit() wrapper function invoked the kernel
system call of the same name.  Since glibc 2.3, the wrapper function
invokes exit_group(2), in order to terminate all of the threads in a
process.

the _exit function needs to call a library function with the 2.3 version of glibc. I think debian 12.6 uses glibc 2.3 and other systems you mentioned uses a prior version. However, I am not sure how you were able to compile it statically if this is the case.

This looks like a defect on i386 Linux. In the end I just made a change so that the testcase only runs on non-Linux or amd64.
